# Mongo query that requires matching on two arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following collection in MongoDB 3.2.

```
db.collection.insert(
    {
        permissions: [
            {field: 'name', canEdit: true},
            {field: 'age', canEdit: false}
            // ... lots of other fields
        ],
        inputs: [
            {field: 'name', edited: false},
            {field: 'age', edited: false}
            // ... lots of other fields
        ]
    }
);
```

Is there a way to write a MongoDB query that returns all documents that have at least **one field with both** `canEdit = true` and `edited = true`?

The above question expressed in a pseudo manner:

```
find document D where exists
    P in D.permissions
    I in D.inputs
    P.field = I.field and P.canEdit = true and I.edited = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$elemMatch` condition probably since `collection` itself is an array like

```
db.collection_name.find(
  { collection: { $elemMatch: { "permissions.canEdit": true, "inputs.edited": true } } })
```

Comment: I slightly modified the collection example. The query you are proposing looks for canEdit and edited flags independently from the field. What I need to check is `P.field = I.field and P.canEdit = true and I.edited = true`